# Default parameters: Calculate splitting a check between diners

Tags: python

Can anyone help me writing the `split_check()` function?.

The problem statement is:

> Write a split_check function that returns the amount that each diner
> must pay to cover the cost of the meal. The function has 4 parameters:
> bill: The amount of the bill. people: The number of diners to split
> the bill between. tax_percentage: The extra tax percentage to add to
> the bill. tip_percentage: The extra tip percentage to add to the bill.
> The tax or tip percentages are optional and may not be given when
> calling split_check. Use default parameter values of 0.15 (15%) for
> tip_percentage, and 0.09 (9%) for tax_percentage

I need to calculate the amount of tip and tax, add to the bill total, then divide by the number of diners.

```
bill = float(input())
people = int(input())

#Cost per diner at the default tax and tip percentages
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(bill, people))

bill = float(input())
people = int(input())
new_tax_percentage = float(input())
new_tip_percentage = float(input())

# Cost per diner at different tax and tip percentages
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(bill, people, new_tax_percentage, new_tip_percentage))
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried anything yourself to achieve this? Can you share this with us? Are there specific problems you are having with getting your code working?  We'd like to help you to be a better programmer rather than just doing work for you. The aim of this forum is not to write code for people, but rather to help discuss specific coding issues and aid the asker and those who come along in the future in a better understanding of the languages and tools involved.  (see https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: this is the solution i came up with.                                                                            def split_check(bill, people, tax_percentage=0.15, tip_percentage=0.09):
    bill = (input())
    people = (input())
print('cost per dinner:', split_check(bill,people, tax_percentage=0.075))

Comment: Abiyu, please put your code in the original question, not in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking all of the comments into account to understand the problem completely, here's an answer that produces the right result:

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.15, tip = 0.09):
    tax = bill * tax 
    tip = bill * tip
    return (bill + tax + tip)/people
    
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(25, 2))
```

Or more concisely:

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.15, tip = 0.09):
    return bill * (1.0 + tax + tip) / people
    
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(25, 2))
```

Result:

```
Cost per diner: 15.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see only `bill` and `people` are required, so you should add default values to your arguments:

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.09, tip = 0.15)
```

That means that if only two arguments are given, like in the first case, the tax and tip percentages will be 9% and 15% respectively. You should add to `bill` the amount `bill*tax` and `bill*tip`. In the end, you'll divide the bill by the number of people and return it.

So we have this:

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.09, tip = 0.15):
    taxes = bill * tax
    tips  = bill * tip
    return (bill + taxes + tips) / people
```

---

You can also check if `people` is not smaller or equal to 0, if the arguments are numbers and not strings for example, and if `tax` and `tip` are between 0 and 1, etc. using a `try`/`except` block.

Comment: You are forgetting to include the original bill amount in the final amount.  If either `tax` or `tip` are `0`, your final result wiil be `0`.  Also, it looks like you want to calculate the tax based on the bill + the tip amount.  This isn't right.  The tax should be computed on just the bill amount.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant `+=` and not `=`. Thanks.

Comment: when I entered 25, 2 as input I get 0, but the expected pout put 15.5?

Comment: @AbiyuT I fixed my mistake, read my previous comment. Just change `=` to `+=`.

Comment: now, I'm getting 12.5, but the expected output was 15.5?

Comment: How is the expected output 15.5? If you have no tax and tips, the bill is 25, and there are two people, each one should pay 25/2 = 12.5. If the exercise is telling you you should get 15.5 as output, that means the default values are not 0. Just change them in the definition.

Comment: Write a split_check function that returns the amount that each diner must pay to cover the cost of the meal.

The function has 4 parameters:

bill: The amount of the bill.
people: The number of diners to split the bill between.
tax_percentage: The extra tax percentage to add to the bill.
tip_percentage: The extra tip percentage to add to the bill.
The tax or tip percentages are optional and may not be given when calling split_check. Use default parameter values of 0.15 (15%) for tip_percentage, and 0.09 (9%) for tax_percentage

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put the instructions.

Comment: Then put 0.15 and 0.09 as default values for tip and tax respectively instead of 0. And don't write `/100` since they're already percentages. I'll fix my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: thank you Chris, Steve found the solution! appreciated your help!

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I did:

1. I named the parameters with all default amounts
2. named new local variables to get new amounts
3. returned the per_person calculation

```
def split_check(bill=0, people=0, tax_percentage=0.09, tip_percentage=0.15):
    new_check = (bill * tax_percentage) + bill
    new_tip = bill * tip_percentage
    per_person = (new_check + new_tip) / people
    return per_person

bill = float(input())
people = int(input())

# Cost per diner at the default tax and tip percentages
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(bill, people))

bill = float(input())
people = int(input())
new_tax_percentage = float(input())
new_tip_percentage = float(input())

# Cost per diner at different tax and tip percentages
print('Cost per diner:', split_check(bill, people, new_tax_percentage, new_tip_percentage))
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
def split_check(bill=0.0, people=0, tax_percentage=0.09, tip_percentage=0.15):
    bill_per_diner = ((bill + ((tax_percentage * bill) + (tip_percentage * bill))) / people)
    return bill_per_diner
```

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph outlines what your parameters needs to be; bill, people, tax percentage and tip percentage. it also tells you that you need a tip of 15% and a tax rate of 9%. so from there you can write your function.

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.09, tip = 0.15):
```

"bill" and "people" will be a user input so they do not get a value. but now you have to define the calculations for the tax, the tip and the split. tax will be bill * tax and tip will be tip * bill, then the total will be bill + tax + tip / people

```
def split_check(bill, people, tax = 0.09, tip = 0.15):
    tax = bill * tax
    tip = bill * tip
    return(bill + tax + tip) / people
```

do not add hard values to the areas that say float(input()), int(input()) or anywhere in your programing that requires an input. These are for user input.